# Help identifying electrical components

Tags: electrical, cad, outlet

Sorry if this inquiry is it a little bit basic and boring, but I need some sort of help with this, and I am really not sure where to look online. I need help identifying several different electrical parts for a waste treatment build I am making a CAD draw up for, and as I am working remotely, my very busy employer has not had enough time to actually tell me what the exact parts are. Sorry for my ignorance, as I am actually a Mechanical Engineering student, and my experience with circuitry is relatively limited.

I don't really need to know the exact model number or anything, just the general name for it, as all I really need is to get a 3D model that looks SOMEWHAT like the object in question. Alternatively, if anyone could point me to a resource that I could somehow use to answer these questions on my own, then I would also appreciate that! Alright, here we go!

First photo:  First of all, what is the name of the... HUB, so to speak, in the middle of this photo? Also, what are the two things just under it?

Second Photo:  What is the name of the two hubs in this photo?

Third Photo: What is the name of the two socket outlet?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would call the boxes in the first two pictures junction boxes.  The third picture shows an outlet box with a weatherproof cover and a duplex outlet.

The photos all appear to show plastic conduit.  The devices below the box in the first photo are some sort of conduit fitting - the photo is too fuzzy, and doesn't show enough of the fittings, to say what the fittings are for.